# Defining registers in UHD

Tags: c++, usrp, uhd

Just for my own clarification, if I were to define a register available on the AD9361 to the ad9361_driver files of UHD, would a script be able to call that register with nothing more than the header files found in one of the examples such as tx_bursts or tx_waveforms.cpp, or is there some workaround I would need to do to use anything defined in that location?

Comment: No, not generally.

What you'd do, optimally, is to add that register address somewhere in the ad9361_driver header files, then add a property tree entry that calls a method that sets the register. Then, you could call that through the property tree (which is a bit awkward, but works)

Comment: But I'm 90% sure this isn't really what you need – this might be a case oft the [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info)

Comment: Well, to ensure that I am asking the right question, I'll start by letting you know I am trying to have a c++ script use registers on the ad9361 within the E310. My issue comes with not quite understanding where exactly I needed to define them or have them accessible for a script to communicate with.